# How to check if someone connected to a Access DB

Tags: c#, ms-access

how can I check in my programm if someone working on a microsoft access db?
Its only allowed that 1 User works on the database with my programm (C#), so I need a way to check this because access is not so good for multiple Users.

thanks

Comment: Doesn't Access create a lock (*.ldb) file, when you open the database file? You could check if an *.ldb exists.

Answer (score 4):

Read up on Exclusive Mode in MS-Access.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/c90b1166-e5ee-43ff-a49b-9efe9f416475/

Comment: Thanks for this advice, I've changed the connectionstring of my program to open the database in exclusive mode but there are no changes. If I open the db with my program in exclusive mode I can still useable even access from any computer without a error that the db is already open.
I've used the following connectionstring:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=#SERVERPATH#;OLE DB Services=-4;Mode=\"Share Exclusive\";Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=passwort1;

Comment: Try using the numeric constant, Mode=12

Answer (score 1):

Ok:

1. There's no reason why access will not be fine with multiple users - however its performance over a network can be a poor and there are better alternatives.
2. If its open there will be a .ldb file - however this may not be the best way to check as it should disappear if the connection is closed and therefore you could easily things up so that there are "strange" concurrent user issues - further, as suggested in the comments, its not reliable (although if it is there and the db is closed you've got bigger problems).
3. @Tim has the first solution right in terms of looking at Exclusive Mode
4. I'd probably also suggest putting your own "lock" file in place rather than relying on any mechanisms in access
5. And if the only reason you want to restrict connections to the file is concerns with concurrent access then you seriously need to review whether you are using the right tools.

Comment: Access in multi-user scenario is usage-dependent. Multiple concurrent reads is more do-able than multiple concurrent inserts. All inserted records are appended to "caboose" of the table, so there can be significant contention for that page. Also, as in any shared-file byte-range locking architecture (as distinct from bona-fide client-server engine), if the network connection is flaky, or if the client PC has any hiccups, then the data on the server can get corrupted if the transport-layer or client problems occur at an inopportune moment. Even a single user has these issues; multi exacerbates.

Comment: I easilyed things up once. I regretted it ;)

Comment: One should not assume that the existence of an LDB file (or the lack of one) tells you anything definitive about whether anybody has the database open or not. That is, the presence of one does not mean someone is using the database, as it can be left in the file system after Jet/ACE closes its connection (though that's not default behavior of Jet/ACE with DELETE permissions on the containing folder).

Comment: Thank you for the solutions, I will try to open the db in exclusive mode.